# Gradle transitive repository dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In my gradle project i have two subprojects, one called `api` and the other `core`:

api.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://repo.spongepowered.org/repository/maven-public/' }
}

dependencies {
    api('org.spongepowered:spongeapi:8.0.0')
}
```

core.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(':api'))
}
```

The problem is that when I try to compile the `core` subproject I get the following error:

```
> Could not find org.spongepowered:spongeapi:8.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
```

Adding the spongepowered repository in core.gradle works, but I wanted to know if there is a way to also add the repository transitive to reduce boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

Repositories used by every subproject (in your case - api & core) can be declared in the settings.gradle file at the root of the project:

settings.gradle

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spongepowered.org/repository/maven-public/' }
    }
}
```